# Get object of jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the amount of children inside the .test div.

but $(this) seems to Refer to the function $.fn.test and not the object I use it on.

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.test = function (x) {
        var xx = $.extend({
            items_Page: 4,
        }, x);

        function initialized() {
            var itemCount;

            ItemCount = $(this).lenght;

            console.log(itemCount);
        }
        initialized();
    }

}(jQuery));


$(".test").test()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
            <div class="tester">test1</div>
            <div class="tester">test2</div>
            <div class="tester">test3</div>
            <div class="tester">test4</div>
            <div class="tester">test5</div>
            <div class="tester">test6</div>
            <div class="tester">test7</div>
            <div class="tester">test8</div>
        </div>
```

Since people misunderstood me. I call the function like this  $('.test').test() aka I want to get the children of the $('.test'), but it has to be dynamic.

so if I change it to $('.horse').test() then it will get all the children of the class horse..

Comment: For (1) Simply use `$('.test').children().length;` to get your answer & (2) You have a typo on the `length` word of your `ItemCount = $(this).lenght;`

Comment: I dont wnat to strong type it since it can called on lots any class or id like a normal funtion. It has to get the children of the div its binded to

Comment: @PeterHansen : Why ? And how do you call your function ?

Comment: typos galore: `itemCount !== ItemCount` and `lenght !== length` You get undefined because you never store anything in `itemCount`. Your code is basically this. `var itemCount; console.log(itemCount);`

Comment: @Aks this is how i call it. $(".test").test(). as you can see i can call it on any function. aka it has to find the children of the object that its called on

Comment: @PeterHansen did you see my last comment.. Your typos are causing you not to see the item so you are not going to be able to select the children.

Comment: @epascarello do you want it to be like this then = ItemCount = $(this).length !== $(this).length; ? because that returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the typos and set up the extend so it returns correctly.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.test = function(x) {

    return this.each(function() {

      var wrapper = $(this);

      var xx = $.extend({
        items_Page: 4,
      }, x || {});

      function initialized() {
        var itemCount;
        itemCount = wrapper.children().length;
        console.log(itemCount);
      }
      initialized();

    });
  }

}(jQuery));

$(".test").test()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="tester">test1</div>
  <div class="tester">test2</div>
  <div class="tester">test3</div>
  <div class="tester">test4</div>
  <div class="tester">test5</div>
  <div class="tester">test6</div>
  <div class="tester">test7</div>
  <div class="tester">test8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What prevents you of using `$('.test').children().length` ?

```js
var childrenAmount = $('.test').children().length;
console.log(childrenAmount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
            <div class="tester">test1</div>
            <div class="tester">test2</div>
            <div class="tester">test3</div>
            <div class="tester">test4</div>
            <div class="tester">test5</div>
            <div class="tester">test6</div>
            <div class="tester">test7</div>
            <div class="tester">test8</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Care, if he got another tag, which is not a div, it'll count.

Comment: @Aks yep, not sure if OP wants a limitation only for `div` tags or just count all children inside `.test` div.

Answer (score 1):

**AFTER YOUR COMMENT**

I tested some function, I think this will do the trick.

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = function() {
      return this.children().length;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

You can call it using `$(".test").myfunction();` and it will return the number of children of the element you passed using Jquery.

But you should care, I think it can act weirdly if you pass more than one element. (And I don't know what your previous code is used for)

**OUTDATED**

Using JQuery, you can do it way more faster.

```
$(".test div").length
// $(".test") = Get the div with the class "test"
// $(".test div") = Get the div inside the div with "test" class
```

Even quicker, **only** if you have no "tester" class tag outside your DIV.

```
$(".tester").length
```

Comment: **I wouldn't recommend the second one** because if the DOM has any other element with class `tester`(even outside the `.test` div) that will be counted as well. Which is a wrong count.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
var ItemCount = $('.test').children('.tester').length;
```

- This will count only `.test`'s children, also
- This will count only children with class `.tester`